# Run C# .exe file in Another Pc

Tags: c#, database

I have made an C# application with local database  .MDF files and .log files in Visual Studio 2015.Now I have to move in another PC.How can I run the .exe file in another pc along with local database.I tried copying the only .exe file and database files in another pc and set the same path of local db files as it was in my PC.I didn't use any SQL server and I don't have much idea about it as it is my very first project.Can my application run if I want to move only local db files and .exe file? I have done this but failed what to add more ? what I am missing?.I have searched but I am very confused.
Will be very thankful for your suggestions.

Comment: Please consider reading "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 0):

You should have the DB listed as one of the projects' dependencies with the proper file paths established.  It sounds like you did that.  Just to be sure, you should place you DB in your project folder somewhere...  Make an individual folder for it; put it in your Resources; put it in your `bin` folder...  Something to where it is directly tied to the project.  For example - the DB's we use at my job are stored at `ProjectName > Project > Install > SubFolderName > Databases > DB` (Obviously file names and extensions redacted).

After you place your DB in a sensible location within your project, just copy and paste the whole project on the new computer.  Keep in mind if you're using `string`s for the file paths to retrieve your files (which you likely are), they may not be valid on the new computer.  You might have to reset those.  I imagine this is your greatest problem.

That's the best I could gather from your post.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this :)